# Magento Fatal error: Call to a member function addLink() - Stack trace included

Tags: php, magento

I just uninstalled 2 extension from magento connect and end up with a 3rd extension fatal error.

http://nutrija.com

Front end of magento is throwing just a white page.
backend - is working normally.

i have already tried disabling "Webinse_DailyDeals" extension, removing that 16th line of code. But no luck.

> ERROR LOG:  [Sun Mar 27 08:11:38 2016] [error] [client 59.96.113.41]
>   PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function addLink()
>   on null in
>   /home/nutrija/public_html/includes/src/Webinse_DailyDeals_Block_Links.php:16
>
> Stack trace:
>   0 /home/nutrija/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(27948): Webinse_DailyDeals_Block_Links->addDealLink('dailydeals_link...')
>   1 /home/nutrija/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(27814): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateAction(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
>   2 /home/nutrija/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(27806): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
>   3 /home/nutrija/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(27810): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
>   4 /home/nutrija/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(27810): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
>   5 /home/nutrija/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(13941): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
>   6 /home/nutrija/public in /home/nutrija/public_html/includes/src/Webinse_DailyDeals_Block_Links.php
>   on line 16

```
<?php
/**
 * AddDealsLink Block
 *
 * @category   Webinse
 * @package    Webinse_DailyDeals
 * @author     Webinse Team <info@webinse.com.com>
 */
class Webinse_DailyDeals_Block_Links extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{

    public function addDealLink()
    {
        $parentBlock = $this->getParentBlock();
        $text = $this->helper('dailydeals')->getDealsConfig('dailydeals_group/label_deals_link');
        $parentBlock->addLink($text, 'dailydeals/', $text, true, array(), 1, null, 'class="top-link-deals"');

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, try to turn off compilation. Next, check why the `$parentBlock` not exists in your layout.